# Structure of files in flask pythonanywhere server?

Tags: csv, web-applications, flask, structure, pythonanywhere

I'm starting in learning how to work in pythonanywhere so I've some problems...
My web app has the structure:

```
    /home/mentor/mysite/servidor/ here I've run.py and the folder app

    inside app there's init.py , views.py and the folders: static,scripts,templates
```

My problem is that inside the web there's a form and when someone clicks on the button a function from scripts is called in views.py. That function needs to read a .csv file (I've kept that file in .../servidor/).

But the webpage doesn't run, it returns a 500 Internal Server Error because OSError: File b'Names.csv' does not exist. 
Why I can solve this? Where I need to put that file? Is that a problem of run.py or WSGI configuration file?

Thank's!

PD.: The code

in viwes.py:

```
 from .scripts.file import function

 @app.route('/func', methods=['POST'])
 def resp():
     l=[request.form['d1'].....]
     f=function(l)
     .....
```

in file.py in scripts folder:

```
  import pandas as pd
  def function(l):
      df=pd.read_csv('Names.csv') #Here is the problem!
      .....
```

Comment: Could you include the code that is accessing the file?

Comment: @Luis Orduz , I've just write it down, it's okay? or do you want to see anymore?

Answer (score 2):

You can open files relative to the Python modules leveraging `__file__`.

```
import os


def open_here(filename, encoding='UTF-8'):
    """Open a file in the same directory as this module."""
    here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    return open(os.path.join(here, filename), encoding=encoding)


# example snippet
def foo():
    with open_here('my_file') as f:
```